# Regex logic comparison simplification

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have multiple complex logic and one of them is comparison of 2 strings.

```
$db_string_param1 = 'AA1 AB AC1 AK1 BKK2';

$file_string_param1 = 'AK1B25';
```

I need to test whether `$file_string_param1` contains any of the content of `$db_string_param1`, delimited by space without making `$db_string_param1` an array.

I am thinking maybe this is possible using regex, and for now I am not that good using complex regex.

Comment: Please explain *"without making `$db_string_param1` an array"*. The only sensible way to do this is to turn one of the strings into a list of tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your data hasn't contain the special character you could use simple `|` in a substitution `s/\s/|/g`.

In below RegEx substitution I have handle the special characters.

Group the space and non word character. Then `e` flag used for evaluate the right-hand side as an expression. Then check if `$1` is defined or not if it is defined use `|` to separate. if it is not defined it means `$2` contain the special character so you could escape the character.

```
$file_string_param1 = 'AK1B25';

$db_string_param1 = 'AA1 AB AC1 AK1 BKK2';

$db_string_param1=~s/(\s)|(\W)/ defined($1) ? "|" : "\\$2" /ge;


$file_string_param1=~m/$db_string_param1/;

print $&,"\n";
```

Comment: This answer would probably be a bit better if it had `\s+` rather than `\s` in the first capture group - otherwise having extra spaces in the `$db_string_param1` could result in false positives.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't suffer from regex injection bug. It will work no matter what characters are separated by whitespace.

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, split ' ', $db_string_param1;

if ( $file_string_param1 =~ /$pat/ ) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Re "*This solution doesn't suffer from regex injection bug*", While this moderator-provided text does imply that other solutions do suffer from this bug, I'd like to point out that mkHun's solution doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You don't explain why you don't want your database parameter converted into an array so it is hard to understand your intention, but this program demonstrates how to convert the string into a regex pattern and test the file parameter against it

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $db_string_param1   = 'AA1 AB AC1 AK1 BKK2';
my $file_string_param1 = 'AK1B25';

( my $db_re = $db_string_param1 ) =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g;
$db_re =~ s/\s+/|/g;
$db_re = qr/$db_re/;

say $file_string_param1 =~ /(?<![A-Z])(?:$db_re)(?![0-9])/ ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

#### output

```
found
```

Comment: Thanks man! If I use an array and loop it, my code will look more complex besides all the other logic involved. I just wanna try to make it simple as possible with all the logic involved.